# Group By In addition to instantiating a class

Tags: c#, .net-core

I have a table in the database
I have table in the DB, containing messages for the user (text,image etc)
I have message name (that means the category), message text (includes the image) and message group that includes all the categories that are relevant (can be null, 1 and more)

I need to bring all the messages that are relevant for the user

```
public async Task<List<MediaDTO>> GetMedia (string UserType)
        {
            List<MediaDTO> results = new List<MediaDTO> ();
            string media = "Media_"+ UserType;
            using (DTS_OnlineContext contextForMessages = new DTS_OnlineContext())
            {
                //(x => businessIds.Contains(x.BusinessId)).ToList();
                //var Images = contextForMessages.Messages.Where(p => p.MessageText.Contains()
                var items = await contextForMessages.Messages.AsNoTracking().Where(x => x.MessageContext == media).ToListAsync();
                if (items.Count > 0)
                {
                    results = items.GroupBy(x => x.MessageName).ToList()
                      .ConvertAll(x => new MediaDTO()
                      { MediaCategories = x.Key, Media = x.ToList().Select(y => y.MessageText).ToList() });

                }


            }
```

but this way I miss the category that include more then one category in messagegroup, and get only those that null.
how can I separate message group for the categorys and give details for each one?